# New to SQL: trouble with being refused access to local Adventureworks installed server

Tags: sql-server, installation, users, connections, visual-studio-2015

Evening,

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015, SSDT, SSMS, SQLExpress2014 and LocalDB.

I'm attempting to do this tutorial: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1e68a88-0f82-415d-becc-78d180d4f845(v=sql.110)

After solving an issue wherein I didn't have the right programs installed; I've tried now installing the AdventureWorks2014.bak file from a microsoft FILELISTONLY and RETRIEVE DATABASE tutorial; it seems to work, but when I then attempt to add a data source view after adding the data source I then get a refused login by the user.

I've tried adding permissions, updating user privilidges and rights, etc, etc, etc. A curious note is that I can't see my new Adventureworksdw2014 database in SSMS or config.

I'm not sure how to login to my locally installed SQL server as well, I can login to my user server and localhost; this solution was well regarded (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)

Any ideas?

I'm at a bit of a loss; I feel I've made a decent effort to work this out but I'm out of ideas for the moment and it's really chewing time hard.

Comment: Could you add the error message? It would help pinpoint the issue(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it;

Turns out following the Word doc explanation guide accompanying the sample database in SSMS works; I just rushed past it.

That feeling when.